# jQuery: Giving Dropdown Menu a Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm using jQuery to give a dropdown menu a height when it opens, so it can push down what's below it when the menu drops down. But the height is too high (102px); I think it should be more like 50px, but it seems to be giving an extra height to the menu, and I don't seem to figure out why. I'd like the height to be just the height of the text, and there's no empty space below.

jQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '#navpanel .mainnav a[href^="/#"]', function(e) {
    if ($(this).parent('li').hasClass('expanded')) {
        $(this).siblings('ul').css('display', 'block').slideDown('linear', function() {
            $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('expanded');

        });
    } else {
        $(this).siblings('ul').css('display', 'none').slideUp('linear', function() {
            $(this).parent('li').toggleClass('expanded');
        });
    }
    var objHeight = 0;
    $.each($('ul.tier1').children(), function() {
        objHeight += $(this).height();
    });
    $('ul.tier1').height(objHeight);
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="mainnav">
    <ul class="tier1">
        <li id="blog">blog</li>
        <li class="">
            <a class="tier1title" href="/collections/newarrivals">New Arrivals</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a class="tier1title" href="/#">Categories</a>
            <ul class="tier2">
                <li class="">
                    <a href="/collections/knits">Knits</a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="/collections/tops">Tops</a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="/collections/dresses">Dresses</a>
                </li>
                <li class="">
                    <a href="/collections/bottoms">Bottoms</a>
                </li>
                . . .
                <li class="">
                    <a class="tier1title" href="/collections/sale">Sale</a>
                </li>
                <li class="registerform">
                    ...
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  #navbar #navpanel .mainnav > ul > .active > ul {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
  }

  #navbar .mainnav > ul > li {
  display: block;
  }

  #navbar #navpanel .mainnav ul.tier1 {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
  }

  #navbar #navpanel .mainnav ul.tier1 > li {
    font-size:13px;
    font-family: 'TradeGothicLTStdCnNo.18';
    padding:0 9px;
  }

  #navbar #navpanel .mainnav ul.tier1 > li:first-child {
    padding-right:80px;
    position:relative;
    left:-10px;
  }

  #navbar #navpanel .mainnav ul.tier1 > li:last-child {
    padding:0;
  }

  #navbar #navpanel .mainnav li li {
    text-align:center;
  }

  #navbar #navpanel .mainnav li ul {
    display:none;
  }

  #navbar #navpanel .mainnav ul.tier2 {
    position:absolute;
    height:auto;
    width:600px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size:11px;
    margin:12px auto 0 auto;
  }

  #navbar #navpanel .mainnav ul.tier2 li {
    padding-right:12px;
  }
```

Comment: From jquery documentation : "Note that .height() will always return the content height, regardless of the value of the CSS box-sizing property. As of jQuery 1.8, this may require retrieving the CSS height plus box-sizing property and then subtracting any potential border and padding on each element when the element has box-sizing: border-box. To avoid this penalty, use .css( "height" ) rather than .height().". Maybe it can help

Comment: create a fiddle with css

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes The dropdown menu works partially through shopify liquid code, so jsfiddle won't do it.

Comment: @EoiFirst I changed it to .css('height'), but it still gives the same height. The ul or li has no border or padding on the bottom.

Comment: add your css code please.

Answer (score 0):

is your margin, padding, border, outline set to 0?

try:

```
$('ul.tier1').css('padding', '0');

$('ul.tier1').css('margin', '0');

$('ul.tier1').css('border', '0');

$('ul.tier1').css('outline', '0');
```

this way it won't magically adds 'extra height'.

Comment: long. it can be added in CSS.

Comment: I added margin:0 padding:0 order:0 outline:0 to the stylesheet. It made the height a little shorter (from 102px to 87px), so I guess it did work, but seems like there's something more, because it's still higher than it should. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's good to add this code at the first line of your css to do everything you want without padding and margins that browsers put in different parts of your webpage.

css:

```
* {margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Comment: I added margin:0 padding:0 order:0 outline:0 to the stylesheet. It made the height a little shorter (from 102px to 87px), so I guess it did work, but seems like there's something more, because it's still higher than it should. Any ideas? Thanks.